# Create new columns for last n rows in dataframe by group dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID  =  c(11041,11041,11041,11041,11041,11041,11042,11042,11042,11063,11063),
  p = c(2.9,3.6,4.8,2.6,2.2,3.9,6.5,2.9,1.4,0.7,5.1)
    )
```

Which gives this output:

```
      ID   p
1  11041 2.9
2  11041 3.6
3  11041 4.8
4  11041 2.6
5  11041 2.2
6  11041 3.9
7  11042 6.5
8  11042 2.9
9  11042 1.4
10 11063 0.7
11 11063 5.1
```

I am trying to create new columns for the last n values (let's say 3) by `ID`, so my new data frame would look like so:

```
      ID   p p1.1 p1.2 p1.3
1  11041 2.9   NA   NA  2.9
2  11041 3.6   NA  2.9  3.6
3  11041 4.8  2.9  3.6  4.8
4  11041 2.6  3.6  4.8  2.6
5  11041 2.2  4.8  2.6  2.2
6  11041 3.9  2.6  2.2  3.9
7  11042 6.5   NA   NA  6.5
8  11042 2.9   NA  6.5  2.9
9  11042 1.4  6.5  2.9  1.4
10 11063 0.7   NA   NA  0.7
11 11063 5.1   NA  0.7  5.1
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to specify the last n values, so that if I want the last 5 (creating p.1, p.2, p.3, p.4, p.5) I can do this. But n could be any number, like 3,5,10,15, etc.

With `dplyr`, I have tried both `spread` and `pivot_wider` but could not get them to work.

Comment: Could you explain the rule for the new column? How to get the values in p1.1 form p, for example?

Comment: yes, of course. In p1.1, it will be the third previous value by ID, if that makes sense. So ID 11041, the first entry is NA because it is the first entry. This is the case for the second entry also. But the third will be 2,9 as it is the value 2 rows above in p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data.table `shift` like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c(paste0("p1.",1:3)):=shift(p, 2:0), by=ID][]
```

Output:

```
       ID   p p1.1 p1.2 p1.3
 1: 11041 2.9   NA   NA  2.9
 2: 11041 3.6   NA  2.9  3.6
 3: 11041 4.8  2.9  3.6  4.8
 4: 11041 2.6  3.6  4.8  2.6
 5: 11041 2.2  4.8  2.6  2.2
 6: 11041 3.9  2.6  2.2  3.9
 7: 11042 6.5   NA   NA  6.5
 8: 11042 2.9   NA  6.5  2.9
 9: 11042 1.4  6.5  2.9  1.4
10: 11063 0.7   NA   NA  0.7
11: 11063 5.1   NA  0.7  5.1
```

One way to generalize would be as follows:

1. Make helper function

```
f <- function(v,n) {
  setNames(shift(v,(n-1):0), paste0(deparse(substitute(v)),".",1:n))
}
```

2. Apply function by ID; here I use `n=5`

```
df[, f(p,5), by=ID]
```

Output:

```
       ID p.1 p.2 p.3 p.4 p.5
 1: 11041  NA  NA  NA  NA 2.9
 2: 11041  NA  NA  NA 2.9 3.6
 3: 11041  NA  NA 2.9 3.6 4.8
 4: 11041  NA 2.9 3.6 4.8 2.6
 5: 11041 2.9 3.6 4.8 2.6 2.2
 6: 11041 3.6 4.8 2.6 2.2 3.9
 7: 11042  NA  NA  NA  NA 6.5
 8: 11042  NA  NA  NA 6.5 2.9
 9: 11042  NA  NA 6.5 2.9 1.4
10: 11063  NA  NA  NA  NA 0.7
11: 11063  NA  NA  NA 0.7 5.1
```

Comment: ok, and in the last output, is there a way to keep `p`, like in the first output you provided?

Comment: you could `cbind(df$p, df[, f(p,5), by=ID])`

Comment: you could also do like i did in the first example `c(paste0("p1.",1:5)):=.f(...)`, but then we are creating the names twice, once here and once in the function

Comment: ok great, this appears to give the desired results!